# add header to pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext

how i can add header to each PDF page using iText 5.0.5.

Answer (score 18):

This is covered in [chapter 5 of iText In Action, 2nd ed](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=5).  The code examples are all freely available online.  In particular [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) and [MovieHistory2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103) both deal with *page* headers and footers.

It boils down to using a `PdfPageEvent` implementation (usually derived from `PdfPageEventHelper` to cut down on boilerplate) to draw into the page's Direct Content during an EndPage (or BeginPage I suppose) event.

You have to know where you want them, and you have to draw using a `PdfContentByte` instance, so you can't use the high-level Paragraph/Chapter/Chunk/Image/etc classes.  You have to draw-this-there, draw-that-here.  `ColumnText` can help a bit... but only for Plain Text.  Anything even remotely fancy and you're on your own.

Comment: This should be elected as best answer :)

Comment: I need to add Logo Image in Header, can we insert image in header?

Comment: Yes.  Follow the links, it's all explained.

Answer (score 3):

See the below link having video to show you.

http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=4

For Header-Footer:
http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ITextSharpHelperClass.aspx

Please Vote if this helps to you.

Comment: Actually, that's only for TABLE headers and footers, not for pages.