# iText5.1.0 set header and footer in document

Tags: java, servlets, itext

i m using servlet to view pdf file as using response setContentType pdf.

I want to set Header and Footer of Document generated by IText 5.1.0.

Please Help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [add header to pdf using iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062898/add-header-to-pdf-using-itext)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget about the servlets for a second.  Make sure you can get the header/footer to work locally.

Edit: I was a bad SO user by posting about outdated HeaderFooter stuff.  It seems a lot of people are doing this, making it extremely hard to find succinct examples of this question.  [add header to pdf using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062898/add-header-to-pdf-using-itext) answers this question.

Here seems to be the correct way to do it: (Modified from http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104 ):
[image]
https://gist.github.com/977502

```
/*
 * This class is part of the book "iText in Action - 2nd Edition"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie (ISBN: 9781935182610)
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/examples/
 * This example only works with the AGPL version of iText.
 *
 * Modified by Nick Dunn (http://developmentality.wordpress.com) to
 * focus on just the PDF header aspect.
 */

package part1.chapter05;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MovieCountries1 {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "example_result.pdf";

    /**
     * Inner class to add a table as header.
     */
    class TableHeader extends PdfPageEventHelper {
        /** The header text. */
        String header;
        /** The template with the total number of pages. */
        PdfTemplate total;

        /**
         * Allows us to change the content of the header.
         * @param header The new header String
         */
        public void setHeader(String header) {
            this.header = header;
        }

        /**
         * Creates the PdfTemplate that will hold the total number of pages.
         * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onOpenDocument(
         *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
         */
        public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            total = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
        }

        /**
         * Adds a header to every page
         * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
         *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
         */
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
            try {
                table.setWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2});
                table.setTotalWidth(527);
                table.setLockedWidth(true);
                table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
                table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                table.addCell(header);
                table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                table.addCell(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()));
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(total));
                cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                table.addCell(cell);
                table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
            }
            catch(DocumentException de) {
                throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fills out the total number of pages before the document is closed.
         * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onCloseDocument(
         *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
         */
        public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                    new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1)),
                    2, 2, 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws    DocumentException 
     * @throws    IOException
     * @throws    SQLException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {

        // step 1
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 54, 36);
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        TableHeader event = new TableHeader();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        // step 3 - fill in the document
        document.open();

        event.setHeader("Hello!");
        document.add(new Paragraph("Testing."));
        document.newPage();
        event.setHeader("There!");
        document.add(new Paragraph("Testing."));

        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {
        new MovieCountries1().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
}
```

Comment: A: Good advice: "forget about the servlets for a second".  Always get your app working outside servlets before adding them into the mix.

Comment: B: HeaderFooter hasn't been a part of iText for Quite Some Time.  Certainly not a part of 5.1.

Comment: @Mark Storer thanks for the information, I've updated my answer accordingly.