# how to add header and footer in PDF to be generated using iText in JSP only

Tags: java, jsp, itext, jsp-tags

I have gone through many post but I am not getting anything useful, as they are all about adding header and footer to existing PDF. What I want is that i want to create header and footer automatically at runtime when PDF is created.

I don't have much knowledge of java, so these classes and interface are out of my knowledge

what I have tried is

### Jsp Page

```
    <%

Phrase header;
PdfPTable footer;


try{

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 54, 54);
// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\lata.pdf"));
HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));
writer.setPageEvent(event);//**problem: The constructor HeaderFooter() is undefined**
// step 3
document.open();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
document.add(new Phrase("lata "));
}
document.close();
}catch(Exception e){
}%>
```

Is it possible to call that function or create a PDF file with iText just by placing code in the JSP page or any other simple solution? What I want to add image at the end of every pdf page.

Answer (score 0):

***ANSWER TO: Is it possible to call that function or create a PDF file with iText just by placing code in the JSP page or any other simple solution?***

To develop this code, first do it in a simple java application, say inside

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

That is the hardest part, especially as iText is concerned.

When it works,

- port the code to a JSP,
- setting the content type to PDF ("application/x-pdf").
- and making sure there is no additional output between `%>` and `<%`,
- output the file data (write to `response.getOutputStream()`).

or instead of immediately outputting the PDF:

- redirect to a written copy of the PDF in the web directory.

Porting to JSP:

1. The import statements can be placed in the page directive.
2. Declarations of global constantsand methods/functions can be placed in `<%! ... %>`.
3. Add the required library jars.

You will need to search examples.

---

I take it, that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018299/itext5-1-0-set-header-and-footer-in-document) was your source. To create the inner class TableHeader aka HeaderFooter:

```
<%!
class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
...
}
%>
```

Comment: i heve already created pdf in jsp...idn't want to do it in java

Comment: now i just want the codeof adding header and footer in jsp to be added to that pdf created

Comment: Then it seems that only `new PDFHeader()` is the problem.

Comment: not exactly i am not able to call setPageEvent() for every pdf page fr header and footer

Comment: HeaderFooter hasn't been a part of iText for Quite Some Time. Certainly not a part of 5.1. - from @MarkStorer

Comment: hmm i agree so now what can be the solution?

Comment: It the "this" link above, their TableHeader fulfills the HeaderFooter role. Realise your code there. I will not code it out.