# How to add header in iText 5.2.1?

Tags: java, itext

I use iText 5.2.1 and I have already created Document object.

like this:

```
document.addHeader("hello");
```

Why don't I see the header on the PDF File?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add header to pdf using iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062898/add-header-to-pdf-using-itext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Page Events. Many good answers have been provided already on StackOverflow, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072468/1065525), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9175638/1065525).

Comment: Your answer is of great help to me.Thanks for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("FicheClient.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("hello World",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
        document.add(new Paragraph("---------------------------------------"));
        document.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Raport saved ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```